# What value to assign if a dynamic web element doesn't have any value

Tags: java, parsing, selenium-webdriver, logic

I am trying to get data from a dynamic web element and after some logical test i want to do some operation (depending on the results of if and else block). I am not able to figure out what to do if the dynamic webelemnt does't have any value i.e, if its null or 0. 
In this code ==>> String error = wb.getText(); , when we have some value in error then its getting printed but when it does not have any value then it won't print anything and also it is getting printed at only first cycle of while and after words it does't print anything.

```
Code-          
      int i=1;
      int j=1;
      while(i==1){
      String error = wb.getText();
      if(! error.equals(null)){ 
      k0 = Integer.parseInt(error);
      }//if for massage 
      else if(error.equals(null)){
          k0 =0;
      }//else if
      int expected =16;
      if(expected==k0){
          Thread.sleep(4000);
          System.out.println("Readable Massage = "+error +"k0 = "+k0);
      }else{
          driver.navigate().refresh();
          new Play_Music_Using_MouseLocation().play_music_using_mouse_location();
          i++;
      }//else

      //Counting number of runs
      System.out.println("Number of run = " + j);
      j++; 
    }//while

Output at the console --

Readable Massage = 16  k0 = 16
Number of run = 1

Readable Massage = 16
Number of run = 2

Readable Massage = 16
Number of run = 3

Readable Massage = 16
Number of run = 4

Readable Massage = 16
Number of run = 5

Readable Massage = 16
Number of run = 6
```

As you can see from the output its printing the value of k0 after parsing it only at the first run and after words i am getting only the value of error.
Am i doing mistake in the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if(! error.equals(null))  **Should be**    if(error!=null)

If you also want to check that the error String is not empty than the condition should be:

```
if(error!=null && !error.isEmpty())
```

Note: also make sure that **wb** itself is not null

```
if( wb!=null ) 
  {// your logic 
  } 
else 
  {// Logic when it's null
  }
```

Comment: @Shantanu what do you mean it doesn't work? This is how you check if a String (or any other object) is not null.

Comment: i tried if(! error.equals(null)) as well as if(! error.equals("")) but got no result. Are you sure we can use if(error!=null) because i am trying to compare two strings

Comment: @Shantanu null it's not a String! Two compare 2 Strings you would use equals but not to check if it's null! If you also want to check for the Empty String just then the condition will be: if(error!=null && !error.isEmpty())

Comment: @Shantanu I just updated the answer to show how to check for empty String ("") as well.

Comment: Getting java.lang.NumberFormatException exception when using null instead of ""

Comment: @Shantanu where? on which line?